# Boosting Ensemble and Support Vector Machines

Tags: machine-learning, svm, boosting, ensemble-learning, adaboost

[Using Adaboost with SVM for classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27764)

I read the answers to the above question and got an idea of what is being talked about in the papers cited. My question is about the theoretical difference in the results between a model where SVM is treated as a weak classifier and boosted and another model using Adaboost or other boosting methods independently and SVM independently and stacking the results. Will they perform the same?